# How to enable context menu on a VerticalHeaderItem inside a QTableWidget?

Tags: user-interface, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I have QTable widget, where I set

```
setVerticalHeaderItem(0, QTableWidgetItem("some header", 0))
```

I set a contex menu by

```
setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
```

and it works fine on my table's elements other than 1st column, i.e. a VerticalHeaderItem. Basically, when I right-click on 1st column item a context menu doesn't pop up, while clicking on any other elements >1st column causes the context menu to pop up (populated with the QActions I defined, not shown here for clarity).

Is there any attribute I should set in order to make 1st (VerticalHeaderItem) column react to right-click? Qt.ItemFlags maybe? If so, could anyone write a code snippet how to set it properly? Preferably in Python, but C++ would be also OK.

My conf: QT 4.5.2, PyQT 4.5.4, under Windows XP SP2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headers are widgets on their own. So, set the context menu policy on `myTableWidget.verticalHeader()`.

Comment: To ask a followup question (I just run into exactly the same problem) - how does one then extract the row that was clicked?